# ExtJs : How to use existing page in Tabpanel or panels

Tags: extjs, external, tabpanel

I have a question. Of late I have created different pages using ExtJs with backend database. Now I want to put things all together. How can I create a main page that is a view port and its regions are different pages? just like Frames in HTML?

Another, instead of opening new page for some menu option, how (or whether it can be) do I create a new tab in existing Tabpanel in center. The containts should be the page that I have already created (in ExtJS with store, DB etc)?

I know we can have html config option for tabsa

Hope I'm able to make out what I want to say.

Thanks for the response!

Tushar Saxena

Comment: I think I have got a solution.. may be we can use autoLoad option.. i'll research more over it.. in the mean type if you may please want to throw some important aspect.. please do the same!! Best Regards: Tushar

Answer (score 0):

Draw an ExtJs Panel and set the `contentEl` config option to the div id of your page(Make the whole code of your page as a div.). It will render all the elements in that div to the panel.